# QuantLib error: `RuntimeError: negative local vol^2 at... the black vol surface is not smooth enough` for calibrating the SLV model

Tags: quantlib, stochastic-volatility, calibration, local-volatility, volatility-surface

I am trying to generate the SLV process using QuantLib on real SPX data. The issue that I am having is that calendar arbitrage is being violated. I put my data in a list in my code, and am using $r\approx 0.05, q\approx 0.015$. The IVs were calculated from the option prices (all OTM) using last solved price. Does anyone know any remedies?

````python
today = ql.Date().todaysDate()

# [[(T_1,K_1), (T_2,K_1),...] , [(T_1,K_2),....]]
prices = [[ 69.36,  87.05, 135.98, 212.2 ],
       [ 81.75, 106.  , 150.07, 226.14],
       [113.5 , 154.68, 253.81, 427.4 ],
       [ 86.18, 126.76, 223.84, 395.11],
       [ 62.3 , 107.33, 195.35, 371.29]]


S_0 = 5117.09

today = ql.Date(15,3,2024)        # Last trading day before market close
endDate = ql.Date(20,3,2025)

# Set up a Heston process
riskFreeTS = ql.YieldTermStructureHandle(ql.FlatForward(today, 0.05, ql.Actual365Fixed()))
dividendTS = ql.YieldTermStructureHandle(ql.FlatForward(today, 0.015, ql.Actual365Fixed()))

initialValue = ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(S_0))
v0 = 0.005
kappa = 0.8
theta = 0.008
rho = 0.2
sigma = 0.1

hestonProcess = ql.HestonProcess(riskFreeTS, dividendTS, initialValue, v0, kappa, theta, sigma, rho)

# Set up a local vol surface

expirationDates = [ql.Date(17,5,2024), ql.Date(21,6,2024), ql.Date(20,9,2024), ql.Date(21,3,2025)]


strikes = [5050, 5100, 5150, 5200, 5250]

# [[(T_1,K_1), (T_2,K_1),...] , [(T_1,K_2),....]]

IVs = [[0.13415, 0.13182, 0.14318, 0.16104],
 [0.1245, 0.1305, 0.13866, 0.15777],
 [0.13741, 0.14122, 0.15491, 0.17616],
 [0.1314, 0.13691, 0.15111, 0.17232],
 [0.12502, 0.1382, 0.14718, 0.17227]]


impliedVols = ql.Matrix(IVs)

localVolSurface = ql.BlackVarianceSurface(today, ql.NullCalendar(), expirationDates, strikes, impliedVols, ql.Actual365Fixed())
localVolHandle = ql.BlackVolTermStructureHandle(localVolSurface)
localVol = ql.LocalVolSurface(localVolHandle, riskFreeTS, dividendTS, initialValue)

localVol.enableExtrapolation()

# Calibrate Leverage Function to the Local Vol and Heston Model via Monte-Carlo
timeStepsPerYear = 365
nBins = 201
calibrationPaths = 100000
mandatoryDates = []
mixingFactor = 0.9

generatorFactory = ql.MTBrownianGeneratorFactory()

hestonModel = ql.HestonModel(hestonProcess)
stochLocalMcModel = ql.HestonSLVMCModel(localVol, hestonModel, generatorFactory, endDate, timeStepsPerYear, nBins, calibrationPaths, mandatoryDates, mixingFactor)

# Error cause by line below !
leverageFct = stochLocalMcModel.leverageFunction()

process = ql.HestonSLVProcess(hestonProcess, leverageFct, mixingFactor)


```
````